# PHP is very slow when printing a large amount of information

Tags: php, performance, printing

I have an application where I need to retrieve a large amount of rows from the database and then print them all on the screen. I've checked the mysql queries, and that's not where the problem is. The problem is the rows all need to be printed on the same page, with no pagination, and it takes a long time (I'm talking about a table with several thoudands of rows). Is there any way to speed things up? The only thing I've found on Google is using "," instead of "." when using echo. I'll be testing this to see if there is any improvement, but I'm not sure it will make such a big difference.

Comment: Are you sure it's PHP that's being slow, and not the transferring of a huge HTML file?

Comment: I think there's a setting where you can have it start sending the file before the PHP is finished executing too...

Comment: Hi, have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php make sure you don't buffer your output.

Comment: Are you using memcached, APC or Zend Optimizer yet? Do you gzip the content before sending it to the client? Make sure you *enable* output buffering.

Comment: Try downloading the script's output with something OTHER than a browser. Such as command-line curl or wget. Most likely your "long time" is actually the browser struggling to parse/render a table that size, and not a slow script or network connection.

Comment: My money goes on the browser choking on your monster table.

Comment: @MarK, @Marc B, @Andrew Heath: You are all right, the size of the file and the browser seem to be the main problem. In Chrome, for example, the load time is better, but unfortunately the people using the application are only using IE7. The best thing to do may be to try and suggest a makeover for that particular page so that some sort of pagination is possible.

Comment: @Gordon: gzip is not enabled on the server, and I don't have access to any of the settings. I talked to the people that do have access about enabling it. As far as memcached or anything like that, unfortunately it doesn't look like it's going to happen any time soon. Output buffering is enabled.

Comment: Others pointed out: php hardly is the bottleneck. If unsure to a bit of profiling of the code. You will probably find that the php is fast, the query might be next but the real slow part is within the browser. Thinks like fixed table layout (`table-layout: fixed`) might help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is unlikely PHP, it's the massive amount of HTML being output to the browser. You could verify this yourself by saving the page that you get, then loading the static file from your hard drive.

If you are outputting a large table, then the browser will often have problems with "redrawing" it as content is loaded. This can be minimized by setting a fixed width for all the columns. Just do this on the first row.

You can also jump out of the PHP block to output most of the HTML, then just print the variables where appropriate. Here's an example, assuming all your data is in the `$rows` variable:

```
<?php
  // some code here
?>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th width="50">Header 1</th>
  <th width="200">Header 2</th>
  <th width="150">Header 3</th>
  <th width="100">Header 4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ( $rows as $r ) : ?>
<tr>
  <td><?=$r['var1']?><td>
  <td><?=$r['var2']?><td>
  <td><?=$r['var3']?><td>
  <td><?=$r['var4']?><td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php
  // continue here if necessary
```

Note: if you don't have PHP short tags enabled you'll need to do `<?php echo $r['var1'] ?>` instead.

Finally, you can try adding gzip compression. It's best done at a server level but in PHP you can do add the line `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` as the very first line of PHP code right after `<?php`.

If this still does not help, then it's a simple fact that your table is *way too big*. You'd be much better off using pagination or filtering to keep the size down.

Comment: After several tests it seems that although some optimization here and there speeds things up a little, the main problem is the size of the table. So I'll just have to convince them to do some sort of pagination there. I didn't think about the column width before, there are some columns in the table that don't have a fixed width. I'll change that and see if it helps. Thank you.

Comment: A minor improvement might be to break it up into smaller tables... every 50 items or so, start a new table. You can style it so it looks seamless.

Comment: For similar problem I had to create a C++ PHP extension for rendering the table. It's lightning fast compared to PHP code. Another issue is that during rendering PHP consumes a lot of CPU, putting high load on the server.

Comment: There is a typo in the table body use `</td>` to close the cells. (Edit que is full otherwise I would have made the change now). Having said that. To reduce the size (a little) you could do without th `</td>` and `</tr>` these are optional.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is not your bottleneck. Here is a [presentation](http://talks.php.net/show/confoo10) that I've attended about PHP performance by Rasmus Lerdorf, the guy who created PHP. PHP is one of the last things that you have to worry in terms of performance. You can print millions of row entries and do complex calculations without problem. Before throwing it to PHP check your code, your queries, your webserver settings.

As Mark suggested you can use [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) to send output to browser while still getting information from db.

Comment: This is the video of that presentation http://about.digg.com/blog/rasmus-lerdorf-php-performance

Comment: Thank you for the presentation, it is very useful. I've been checking the code and the queries and did some optimization, but that doesn't seem enough. I'll look into using flush and see if that makes things better.

Comment: Well you should then give an example of a fast executing PHP code. Redirecting everyone to a presentation is not much helpful.

Comment: So my comment was downvoted...
On slide 18 of the presentation there's "we see that the Database is the bottleneck, as it should be." although 32,39% of time was spent on the database. I've created a C++ PHP extension to render HTML from large amount of rows from database and there 99% of the time is spent on the database.